# Jaspersoft Studio. Concating String and Date element doesn't work

Tags: jasper-reports, simpledateformat, concatenation

Im working with Tibco Jaspersoft Studio. My problem occurs when im trying to concat the String value and the Date value in the Text Field.

I've tried following expressions:

> $F{policyPlace}  + ", " + new
>   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").parse($F{policyDate})

[]

> $F{policyPlace}  + ", " + (new
>   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").parse($F{policyDate}))

[]

> $F{policyPlace}  + ", " + String.valueOf(new
>   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").parse($F{policyDate}))

[]

> $F{policyPlace}  + ", " + (String.valueOf(new
>   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").parse($F{policyDate})))

But its doesn't work as expected.

I get result like this:
[not good result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abLwI.png)
As you can see - the date isn't formatted as expected :/

What I want to get (result) - it's something like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMyzS.png)

Did anyone have similar problem like me? Can you give me some advice, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").parse($F{policyDateTraor}` just parses your `java.lang.String` with the format that you are giving to it into a `java.util.Date`.

You are not saying anywhere that you want a specific pattern for the output. You need to format this new date with the desired pattern, something like this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm").format(
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").parse($F{policyDateTraor}))
```

If you are using this code in more than one place, then it is better to create a separate class in order to avoid creating the formatter instances each time.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks for you answer **Narcis**
I've found a solution already.
I did it using **msg()** function.
Like this:

> msg("{0}, {1}", $F{policyPlace},  new
>   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").parse($F{policyDate}))

Answer (score 0):

It should be .format, not .parse. The correct code will be as follows.

```
$F{policyPlace} + ", " + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").format($F{policyDate})
```